# AngularJS (routing) cannot find .html templates in Maven SpringBoot project in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm learning AngularJS with Spring Boot. I have created a SpringBoot project and imported it into Eclipse and without writing any Java code I'm trying to make AngularJS front end template work with routing. I have necessary angular scripts included in the project and I'm doing everything as in tutorials on w3schools and on spring website. The same code works fine if I create a very simple app using just html and js not using any IDE, but it fails in Eclipse.

The project directory in Eclipse:

```
-src/main/java
|-com.package
|---Application.java
|---ViewController.java
-src/main/resources
|---static
|-----app
|------app.module.js
|-----angular-route.min.js
|-----angular.min.js
|-----angular.min.js.map
|-----style.css
|---templates
|-----first.html
|-----index.html
|-----main.html
|-----second.html
```

Navigation in index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <header class="header">
        <a ng-href="#/!">Main</a>
        <a ng-href="#!first">First</a>
    </header>   
    <div>   
        <ng-view></ng-view>         
    </div>
</body>
```

app.module.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        template: 'main.html'
    })
    .when("/first", {
        templateUrl: "first.html"
    })
    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'second.html'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

As in case of the first route within `app.config` , it will work fine in each case if I use `template` instead of `templateUrl`.

In case of each of the .html templates they contain some dummy code for example:

```
<p>first</p>
```

When I check in dev-tools, in the Network tab I can see 404 as a response for a request for a template. In the Console I can see the error message as follows.

```
Error: "[$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Ftemplates%2Ffirst.html&p1=404&p2="
```

From AngularJS website I learned it means there's something wrong with the path. I tried to modify the path as in `"/first.html"`, `"./first.html"`, `"/templates/first.html"` but the result was the same.

I do not understand what the issue is. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: I thought it might be useful to add the code for ViewController.java:

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "/templates/first.html" should worked, but i think your browser already in cache, try to checked  DevTools -> settings -> Disable cache (while DevTools is open), and refresh your page

Comment: I refreshed the page multiple times, cleared cache too. I also tried 3 different browsers. The result is the same. Changing the settings as above did not help I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked fine - I mean the navigation - as soon as I moved all html files into src/main/resource/static folder within the project in Eclipse.

So the project structure should be like this:

```
-src/main/java
|-com.package
|--Application.java
|--ViewController.java
-src/main/resources
|-static
|--app
|----app.module.js
|--angular-route.min.js
|--angular.min.js
|--angular.min.js.map
|--first.html
|--index.html
|--main.html
|--second.html
|--style.css
|-templates
```